# subtracting vec3 in vertex shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I want to subtract an offset from a vec3 in GLSL, vertex shader but all I see is black screen.
The following code compiles fine:
`gl_Position = vec4(rot_env*(p_env), 1.0);`

but when I just add an all zero vec3 it my p_env, it shows nothing on screen. Here is the code which does not run
`gl_Position = vec4(rot_env*(p_env-vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)), 1.0);`

Any ideas why? When a similar subtraction works for me in another shader file i wrote. Here is the line from other shader file which works perfectly fine:
    `gl_Position = vec4(rot*(p*8-vec3(-0.2, 0.8, 0)), 1.0);`

Comment: What types are rot_env and p_env?
Also why do you have extra parentheses?  Why not
`gl_Position = vec4(rot_env * p_env, 1.0);` and
`gl_Position = vec4(rot_env * p_env - vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0), 1.0);` ?

Comment: I added the parenthesis just to make the working code as similar as possible to non working one. rot_env is a uniform mat3, where as p_env is in vec3.   Regarding the use of parenthesis in second snippet of code which does not run, it is important to imprement logic as A*(B-C) is not equal to A*B-C